# Trying to load Facebook-Comments plugin in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm trying to view a facebook-comments plugin in a UIWebView on an iPhone application.

I began with Facebook's [iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios), where I implemented Single Sign-On. The app delegate takes care of Facebook's Single Sign-on, then redirects me to my single view controller, which displays a title bar and a UIWebView.

I load the webview with a local file called "comments.html" which has been added and copied to my bundle/project directory.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"comments" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

My html file is the bare-bones version of the plugin implementation, as generated at the [Facebook Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) description site. I plugged in a url and clicked "Get Code." I took the HTML5 code that they provided me, and stuck it in an html file as so

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.bombslo.com" data-num-posts="4" data-width="470"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The UIWebView loads just fine on my simulator. I hosted and launched the html on my device  and it loads fine in Safari. The problem is that **the UIWebView will not load the Facebook-comments plugin in an embedded UIWebView.**

An important thing to note is that I am not getting a blank screen. I see two animated loading bars, typical to Facebook. Also note that the Facebook-generated code comes in both HTML5 and XFBML. I've tried using both.

Comment: if no one knows, i would love an alternative system to integrate user comments in my app. and direction would be awesomely appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  But after integrating with Facebook iOS sdk and by putting the following statement inside the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"your app id" andDelegate:self];
....
}
```

It resolves my problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be resolved by adding http:// to the js.src

Try changing the FB script to this.

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason. It worked on Twitter embeds.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a feed dialoge unexpectedly did the trick for me! I called

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
```

and when closed, the comments plugin is properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these solution, but none of these works. The thing that works for me is setting the **Base URL** of the `UIWebView`. According to the example of the question, lets say i've read data into variable `htmlStr` then the loading strategy would be like following

```
webview.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: URL(string: "http://www.bombslo.com")!)
```

This works for me.