# iOS: FB comments plugin and FB SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-comments

i'm presenting an UIWebView with my html page that contains standard facebook comments plugin. now, if user is not logged in, there is a big "Login to Facebook to Post a Comment" button which opens login page inside UIWebView. after successful login, it loads facebook web app, which is not what i wanted. i need to return to my comments page. how can i implement it? parse request on each `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and allow loading depend on what is there?

i've also tried to hire Facebook SDK for login, but it doesn't seem to work either. apparently, all necessary data is stored inside facebook session class, not interferring with UIWebView's cookies.

what could be the best approach to implement it?

Comment: interested in this but question should probably be worded better

Comment: Perhaps this post will help yo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809249/trying-to-load-facebook-comments-plugin-in-a-uiwebview?rq=1